# Minimize google font request

Tags: html, css, performance, optimization

My homepage have below links, I need to make a common request for this for performance issue.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

Comment: None of that is CSS, only links to it.

Comment: Yes I mean to say requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://fonts.google.com/

Re-select all the fonts you need on google fonts again. The updated api will create a single url for all your fonts combined like so:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,400i,700,700i|Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400|Roboto:400,500i,700,700i,900" rel="stylesheet">`

You might look into reducing the number of font weights you need as they add unnecessary load if you're not using them.

Comment: If I want to add another one like this : family=Dancing+Script:400,700
So should be like this: Dancing:400,700|Script:400,700 ?